# Burninate [forced-unwrapping]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

When I refreshed the front Stack Overflow page, the question at the top had [forced-unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forced-unwrapping) tag. It looked a bit odd, so I did some digging. There are presently [64 questions tagged `forced-unwrapping`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forced-unwrapping) and one follower. The questions are mostly about unwrapping optionals in Swift, and that first one was about preventing a div from wrapping text using CSS.

I do know that in Swift there is the notion of forced unwrapping ([documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)) - but does it really warrant a separate tag?

I don't frankly see this tag as very useful. Should it go?

Comment: Why does it *not* warrant a separate tag? Is this tag causing harm? What would be the advantage of removing it?

Comment: To me it seems excessive, that's all.

Comment: What does "excessive" mean in the context of tags? I have trouble following that logic. If I want to search for questions about a language feature, then this seems like an extremely convenient way of doing so. If I don't care, then I don't sort by the tag.

Comment: Fair point, however in this case "forced unwrapping" is not a language feature, it's an abstract notion.  Basically, _if you do this, then that, then whatever, then it may also be referred to as forced unwrapping_